# Is the proper phrase "Be Discovered" or "Get Discovered"?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, passive-voice, get-be

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is “to get” sometimes used where “to be” could be used?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3072/why-is-to-get-sometimes-used-where-to-be-could-be-used)

I am working on a website and I'm having a little difficulty selecting an appropriate message on the signup page.

Consider the following sentences:

> Sign up to Be Discovered.
>   Sign up to Get Discovered.

Which of these phrases is more grammatically correct? I assume "Get Discovered" is more appropriate however it still feels off. Is there a third option I am missing?

Comment: It's a a question about the _Get_-Passive, all right. Another answer is Barrie's in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44691/grammar-of-married-in-getting-married. But in any case there's a significant amount of confusion between Passives, Participles, and Predicate Adjectives.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sign up *to be* discovered is the correct answer

Comment: It's best to give some rationale for your response rather than simply come out and state it. I think most people would agree that both are perfectly good English sentences.

Comment: @BrettReynolds: I agree with your first sentence, but to me "Sign up to Get Discovered" doesn't sound right. Perhaps usage differs between British and North American English?

Comment: Nope, it's the same in the UK: http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/?c=bnc&q=14572845

Comment: @BrettReynolds: "to get discovered" was not included in the results returned via your link, and when I changed "to get [vvn*]" to "to get discovered", the search returned 0 results. I think this confirms that this is *not* a current usage in British English.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I was referring to the general usage of *get* + past participle, rather than the particular use of *get discovered.* As you say, that particular expression doesn't seem to appear in the BNC but does appear in the COCA, so in this particular instance might indeed be a British vs NA thing.