# What are the difference between "get married" and "be married"?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-usage

In the dictionary

> [get married](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get%20married): to become joined in marriage
>
> They're planning to get married in October.

---

> [married](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/married?q=married) (adj): having a husband or wife

---

So, this is what I think

we often say "**I'm married**" which means "**I have a husband or wife**", we don't say "**I get married**".

We say "**I was married**" which means "**I had a husband or wife in the past but I may or may not have a husband now**"

We say "**I got married**" which is nearly the same as "**I had a wedding**"

> [get married](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/married) (=to have a wedding)
>
> Did you know that they are going to get married?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grammar of "married" in "getting married"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44691/grammar-of-married-in-getting-married) 'Get married' uses the get-passive and is inchoative ('tie the knot'). "We were married in Dunstable" has the same sense, "We got hitched/married in Dunstable". But "We were married" can also have a stative, durative sense: "We were married for over 50 years".

Comment: Whether a past participle is being used as a verb or an adjective has also been thoroughly covered. See, for instance, [Devastated: verb or adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338994/devastated-verb-or-adjective).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, "we have been married for over 50 years" is more accurate if you want to say the action lasted from a point of time in the past to now.

And the link you gave is not a correct answer. "get married" means "to become joined in marriage"

Comment: (1) I didn't and don't. (2) I disagree. As do Barrie England, and The ‘Cambridge Grammar of English’ , Carter and McCarthy. See John Lawler's answer at [What meaning of 'get' is {used} in the 'get paid' {expression}?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/what-meaning-of-get-is-in-the-get-paid-phrase/67009#67009).